# web2py custom reset password

Tags: python, web2py, reset-password

How to create custom reset password form in Web2Py?

**request_reset_password**

```
def request_reset_password(): 
      site_url = 'www.site.com/myproject/'
      auth.settings.request_reset_password_next = URL('account', args='request sent')
      auth.messages.reset_password ='please click this link http://' + site_url+ 'account/reset_password'+ '/?key='+'%(key)s to reset your password' 
      form= auth.request_reset_password()
      form.custom.submit['_data-theme'] = 'e'
      form.custom.submit['_data-ajax'] = 'false'
      return dict(form=form)
```

**reset_password**

```
def reset_password():
      user = db.auth_user
      if request.vars.key:
          key = request.vars.key
          users = db(user.reset_password_key == key).select()
          if not users:
              session.flash='Invalid password reset'
              #redirect(next) 

          form=FORM(INPUT(_name='password', _type="password", requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),INPUT(_type='submit', _value='Click to perform password reset'))
          if form.accepts(request,session):
              key= request.vars.key if request.vars.key else _error()
              password= request.vars.password if request.vars.password else _error()
              users = db(user.reset_password_key == key).select()
             if not users:
                 session.flash='Invalid password reset'
                 #redirect(next) 
             users[0].update_record(password=CRYPT(key=auth.settings.hmac_key)(password)[0],reset_password_key='')
                #session.flash='Password was reset'
                #redirect(next)

      return dict(form=form)
```

To add a view for the both functions try this code .

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}} 
{{=form}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above code is working perfectly